# How to optimize php app with codeigniter?

Tags: php, optimization, codeigniter

I have some very large processing being done in a php application.

I'd like to use one of those scripts/programs which analyze the execution and show you which line of code, or which function, took how much time processing, etc.

Any recommendations?

I'm using the codeigniter php framework so anything that works with it out of the box would be nice, but i'm open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeIgniter has a [built-in profiler](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html).  By default, it shows memory usage, time to load base classes, controller execution time, total execution time, and database query time.

You can use it along with CodeIgniter's [Benchmark class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/benchmark.html) to time other sections of code.

Comment: I'd like to see how much time each line of code takes, for that i'd have to set a lot of benchmarks if i used CI.. not really an option

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is a profiler.

[XDebug has a profiler](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) that i've heard good things about, but haven't tried though.

There is also the [NuPHP Profiler](http://www.nusphere.com/products/php_profiler.htm), but i've heard nothing about it.